# Is there a way to include partials in Craft without setting a path?

Tags: templating

To separate code and avoid duplication I am trying to split up recurring pieces of twig code into partials (think of a nav or a block of services for example).

I tried using `include` but Craft requires me to register a template path. This is also stated in the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating-overview.html#template-paths).

I'm not really sure this is the best way to do it since I would litter my "Sections" with "Singles" which would just function as nothing more include templates.

For example in my `home.twig` I have the following piece of code:

```
<div>
    <div class="container mx-auto px-4 pb-16">
        {% include 'pages/home/dienstenGrid.twig' %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Which would render the corresponding include template. But to be able to do this I have to register this "section"
[image]

Something about this feels gross, and I was wondering if there's a better way to go about this issue. If `This is the way` I will use it this way (Star Wars: The Mandalorian pun intended)

Comment: Couldn't you define a macro which returns your snippet for example and then simply call `{{ macros.dienstenGrid() }}` instead?

Macros are defined in `/craft/templates/partials/macros.twig` as far as I remember

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I found a thread on this stackexchange which pointed out macros. But it seems that macros are more used to create certain markup with variable inputs (like form tags) etc. But I might use macro's.

Comment: Are you [extending a base layout template](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/extends.html)?

Comment: Yes I am. (I have to add more charachters to be able to comment)

Comment: This shouldn't be the case, you can create any twig file without add an associate section to it. Just when you do that, it's a good idea to add ```_``` before the name. Just like ```_partials/home/dienstenGrid.twig```. Then this twig file/template is not visitable by just use the file path.

Comment: I've read your question 5 times but I still don't understand what you're expecting. Twig lets you include a template from anywhere in your templates directory. That included template is then responsible for outputting whatever you tell it to. There's no need to create singles for anything.

Comment: So I have done some more digging, and it's exactly like you guys say, it does work from anywhere in the template. The problem now is that I can't remember how I was doing it before. I'm trying to figure out what I was doing wrong so I could share it, but I forget. When I remember I will let you know. In any case I want to thank you for taking your time to answer my question. :S I'm sorry